# XLOOKUP with two criteria and match_mode set to 1 behaving weird

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two excel spreadsheets and I need to find the next largest depth from a set of samples in my first spreadsheet. I tried to achieve this using `XLOOKUP` with two criteria, and `match_mode` set to "`1`" as I don't have exact matches that I want to find.

Here is the data that I have. The middle is my output using `XLOOKUP` and different `match_mode`s.
I have marked in yellow the cells where the output is not as expected.

[image]

I used the following formulas:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; 1)
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; -1)
=XLOOKUP(A3&B3; $D$3:$D$70&$E$3:$E$70; $E$3:$E$70; "not found"; 0)
```

For example, for Sample1 at Depth 6 I would expect "7.75" as output, and not 60 when using `match_mode` set to `1`.
Sample1 at Depth 9 gives not found, but I would expect 10.85 as output when using `match_mode` set to `1`.

Any idea why excel behaves like this, as it is only in some cases that it does not behave like desired?

(Also, is there a better way to share sample data than via screenshot?)

Comment: I'm assuming your real data doesn't just have the same words "Sample1" everywhere. When combining text and number, it becomes an alphanumeric search so e.g. "sample10" will "sort" before "sample2" because its just comparing character by character in the string.

Comment: You could try zero-padding the numbers before concatenating with the text column e.g. `=TEXT(B2,"000.00")`

Comment: Or just use FILTER: `=@FILTER($E$3:$E$70,($D$3:$D$70=A3)*($E$3:$E$70>=B3))`

Comment: As for sharing data, take just a few minutes getting familiar with https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables# and you'll be a pro at creating tables in no time.  you can paste values from excel directly into the tables.

Comment: Thank you @ExcelEverything , this workaround did help in my current case!